# Expand/shrink region after double-clicking mouse-1

Tags: mouse

How can I change the default double-mouse-1 word selection behavior so that I can move the point around right afterwards to extend/shrink the region? By default, if I forward/backward-char after selecting the word by double-mouse-1, it moves the point, but the mark disappears, so nothing is selected.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change anything.

You just need to *click* **`mouse-3`** *where you want to put the new region limit* (whether enlarging or shrinking, either end, as many times as you like).

IOW:

1. Double-click `mouse1` to select a word or symbol etc. (Or triple-click to select a line, etc.)
2. Click `mouse-3` to extend or retract either end of the region.

Repeat #2 as often as you like, to adjust the region.